# Symfony4: inject service into controller __construct (constructor)

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4, php-7.2

I am having trouble accessing an injected service in the constructor of one of my controllers.

Per http://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/injection_types.html I believe I have done the injection correctly, however when I try to load a view from the controller, I get the following error:

```
Argument 1 passed to Regions\AnalyticsBundle\Controller\PatternsController::__construct()
must be an instance of Regions\AnalyticsBundle\Controller\PatternCacheService, instance of
Regions\AnalyticsBundle\Service\PatternCacheService given, called
in /var/tmp/symfony/cache/dev/ContainerLoHUcSH/getPatternsControllerService.php on line 9
```

It seems like the error indicates that the type hinting in the constructor is trying making it look for an instance in the `*\Controller\*` namespace instead of the `*\Services\*` namespace - what am I doing wrong or not seeing here?

Details of my setup are as follows...

Symfony 4.1.0, PHP 7.2.5

services.yaml

```
services:
    ...

    pattern_cache_service:
        class: Regions\AnalyticsBundle\Service\PatternCacheService
        public: true

    Regions\AnalyticsBundle\Controller\PatternsController:
        arguments: ['@pattern_cache_service']
```

Controller:

```
namespace Regions\AnalyticsBundle\Controller;

class PatternsController extends BaseController
{

    private $pcs;

    public function __construct(PatternCacheService $pcs)
    {
        $this->pcs = $pcs;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot a `use` in your Controller, making PHP think that your service is in the same namespace as your controller.

```
<?php

namespace Regions\AnalyticsBundle\Controller;

use Regions\AnalyticsBundle\Service\PatternCacheService;

class PatternsController extends BaseController
{

    private $pcs;

    public function __construct(PatternCacheService $pcs)
    {
        $this->pcs = $pcs;
    }
}
```

This was actually raised as part of your error message

> Argument 1 passed to Regions\AnalyticsBundle\Controller\PatternsController::__construct()
>   must be an instance of Regions\AnalyticsBundle\**Controller**\PatternCacheService

When what you expected was your controller to need an instance of `Regions\AnalyticsBundle\Service\PatternCacheService`

Answer (score 2):

The class `PatternCacheService` cannot be found in the namespace `Regions\AnalyticsBundle\Controller`.

Add an import:

```
<?php

namespace Regions\AnalyticsBundle\Controller;

use Regions\AnalyticsBundle\Service\PatternCacheService;

class PatternsController extends BaseController
{

    private $pcs;

    public function __construct(PatternCacheService $pcs)
    {
        $this->pcs = $pcs;
    }
}
```

For reference, see

- http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php

Comment: thank you - this fixed it. Since @b.enoit.be was a minute faster I will mark his as correct, however.

Answer (score 2):

1. You don't need a service definition for `pattern_cache_service`. It should autowire your service if `autowire: true` is set.
2. `PatternCacheService` should be `private` as you don't want to access it from within container. Suggested practise!
3. You don't need a service definition for `PatternsController` either.

Note: You should not use "bundles" anymore in Symfony 4 so I would get rid of `AnalyticsBundle`.

Note: Better organise your configuration files as show here: [Organising route, service and parameter configuration files in symfony 4 applications](http://www.inanzzz.com/index.php/post/2c5e/organising-route-service-and-parameter-configuration-files-in-symfony-4-applications).

This should suffice:

**services.yaml**

```
services:
    _defaults:
        autowire: true
        autoconfigure: true
        public: false

    App\:
        resource: '../src/*'
        exclude: '../src/{Entity,....so on .....,Kernel.php}'

    App\Controller\:
        resource: '../../src/Regions/AnalyticsBundle/Controller'
        tags: ['controller.service_arguments']
```

**PatternsController**

```
namespace Regions\AnalyticsBundle\Controller;

use Regions\AnalyticsBundle\Service\PatternCacheService;

class PatternsController
{
    private $pcs;

    public function __construct(PatternCacheService $pcs)
    {
        $this->pcs = $pcs;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for these tips - it helped simplify my services.yaml. The bundles are leftover/legacy from when this ran on 2.8/3.4 :)